# My query is failing when I add a where clause with a dagger, † symbol in it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a SQL query example what I can search a field for this symbol, †. It's a dagger.

I'm running a SQL Server 2012 and I've tried the following code.

The following query returns expected results of thousands of rows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM AUTHORS 
WHERE AFFILIATION LIKE '%†%'
```

Same with this query.

```
SELECT J.ID, AUTHORS.AFFILIATION
FROM JOURNALS AS J
JOIN ISSUES ON J.ID = J.ID 
JOIN articles ON J.ID = ISSUEID 
JOIN authors  ON J.ID = AUTHORS.ID
```

However, add the following WHERE statement to the end of the second query and I get no results.

```
WHERE AUTHORS.AFFILIATION LIKE '%†%'
```

I don't get any errors. Just zero rows returned.

Comment: Maybe in the matched rows after the joins there are not any rows with  AUTHORS.AFFILIATION LIKE '%†%'. Did you check?

Comment: This might be it: 
Line 4 reads ... " ISSUES ON J.ID = J.ID "   Looks like a Typo ... as you're joining J on J

Comment: Recommend using table aliases consistently for all tables in the query for readability and reducing programming bugs.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2012 R2** version - just "2012" - corrected

Comment: I'm a bone head. This query worked:

Answer (score 0):

```
This worked. Thanks, everyone for your tips!

SELECT        TOP (10) authors.id, articles.id AS articleid, authors.ordinal, 
articles.aid, authors.affiliation
FROM            dbo.authors INNER JOIN
                     dbo.articles ON authors.id = articles.id
WHERE        (authors.affiliation LIKE '%†%')
```